# onMenuItemClick switch case selecting multiple cases

Tags: android, menu, switch-statement, onclicklistener, popupmenu

for some reason my switch case is selecting multiple cases for some reason.
Lets say I click sort -> by name, it selects sort -> by name, sort -> by points and statistics (Shown below).
It's not the first time it's happening, it happened in another part of the code as well, and I simple switched it to "if's" and forgot about it. Why would he select multiple values upon click? why the random value?
[image]
Switch Case function:

```
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.optionsMenu_saveListDevice:
            Toast.makeText(this, "saveDevice", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.optionsMenu_saveListServer:
            Toast.makeText(this, "saveServer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.optionsMenu_about:
            Toast.makeText(this, "about", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.optionsMenu_sortByGrade:
            Toast.makeText(this, "sortGrade", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.optionsMenu_sortByName:
            Toast.makeText(this, "sortName", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.optionsMenu_sortByPoints:
            Toast.makeText(this, "sortPoints", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        case R.id.optionsMenu_statistics:
            Toast.makeText(this, "statistics", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        default:
            return false;
    }
```

Show Popup:

```
    public void showPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener((PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener) this);
    popup.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
    popup.show();
}
```

Menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_sort"
    android:title="Sort">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_sortByName"
            android:title="By name" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_sortByGrade"
            android:title="By grade" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_sortByPoints"
            android:title="By points" />
    </menu>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_save"
    android:title="Save">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_saveListDevice"
            android:title="On device" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_saveListServer"
            android:title="On server" />
    </menu>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_statistics"
    android:title="Statistics" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/optionsMenu_about"
    android:title="About" />
```

Comment: can you try logging value of item.getItemID() and the integer values of your other id's and compare the results and  also you should add break in every case statement as it is not a good practice the way you are using it.

Comment: Yup, the break is the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After every toast you should put a `break`.

see this example from Tutorialspoint.com

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      // char grade = args[0].charAt(0);
      char grade = 'C';

      switch(grade) {
         case 'A' :
            System.out.println("Excellent!"); 
            break;
         case 'B' :
         case 'C' :
            System.out.println("Well done");
            break;
         case 'D' :
            System.out.println("You passed");
         case 'F' :
            System.out.println("Better try again");
            break;
         default :
            System.out.println("Invalid grade");
      }
      System.out.println("Your grade is " + grade);
   }
}
```

Comment: That's what happens when you overthink stuff and forgetting the basic ones. Thanks mate!